# How to authentify android app on server side without username/psswd

Tags: android, security, authentication

I have server with some static files which will be served in Android app. What approach should i use to download this files securely? I want to keep URL of my server in "secret". I cant store URL in app coz it can be easily decompiled. So maybe better option is to implement some kind of auth on server side which will provide URL to android client. But how can i authentify android app(that only my app will recieve this credentials). And other problem even if URL will be stored securelly, is it possible to mask comunication with server? So it wont be possible to see URL if  someone will sniff comunication. Any idea how can i do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Verifying Back-End Calls from Android Apps](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2013/01/verifying-back-end-calls-from-android.html) this can help you 
this is a post from google android developer tim bray
from this link

> Most Android apps have some sort of server-side back end, to persist
>   and share data. Even the most basic game needs to remember its
>   players’ high scores. When you’re building your back end, one problem
>   you have to solve is how the back-end code knows what app it’s talking
>   to and who the person using it is.